# How do I strip Aptana down to only what I need?

Tags: simplification

I am very impressed with Aptana, but I am a simple Wordpress developer, who uses jQuery, MySQL, PHP, Wordpress and not much else. I am more than pleased with Aptana's support for these, especially after installing bundles and extensions. However, I have all this support for Capistrano, Python, Ruby, things I never use. Aptana is pretty sluggish for me, and confuses me with way more features than I need. Is there any way to remove this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is just Eclipse with bunch of custom plugins.
You need to disable or uninstall the plugins you do not use.

Plugin manager is located somewhere in the **Help** menu.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F